# Change screen brightness 

Tags: android

i am new to android. i wanted to change brightness to max on button click..but the brightness is not changing.The code is given below please have a look :-

```
          int brightness=255;
        Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),  
                android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, brightness); 
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes(); 
        lp.screenBrightness =brightness;
        getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

apart from this i have added

 in manifest file

what else do i need to add...or what changes i should accomodate so that brightness change is reflected.

Comment: this http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/changing-screen-brightness.html could be helpful...

Comment: You want to chane system brightnes and your question is completely related to screen brightness.I am not sure whether It helps or not but Have a look at this link http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/changing-screen-brightness.html

Answer (score 2):

try using values between 0 and 1. Change your piece of code for this:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
                lp.screenBrightness = 1F;
                getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

Comment: This will change my current window brightness. but i have to change the sytem brightness i.e. y i tried using System.Settings..
That changes the value but the brightness is not reflected on system.

Answer (score 1):

I think this tutorial may help [Try](http://www.41post.com/3503/programming/android-changing-the-screen-brightness)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Try by creating a dummy activity with no UI to do the brightness change.